# Https transparent proxy and SSL certificate validation

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, https

If I setup a transparent proxy for https connections using a SSL certificate signed by my local CA and distributed to all my active directory clients by GPO, may the client (browsers) reject or advise user about certificate issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if you can proxy SSL connections transparently, with a CA cert distributed by GPO. In my experience, all browsers accept the supplied CA, including for certificate pinned sites. The only issue you might run into is clients that send no SNI data (older clients generally - XP/IE the worst offender)

Comment: I have a little question abount certificate CA. Do you know if Firefox uses the windows's CA or it has its own certificate manager?

Comment: I does manage its own CAs using the nss db I think, but it will honour anything you add to the windows CA store too.